# App Store review team reports 'Connection refused' error preventing image loading when using Firebase storage

Tags: android, ios, firebase, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app published on the Apple App store, and I've been having problems getting an updated approved due to issues with loading images. The app review team claims that there are network problems inside my app that prevent images from being loaded properly. Specifically, they have mentioned that the app presents a "Connection refused" error and that content does not load properly.

The app has some social network, instagram-like functionality, allowing users to upload their content, and it's al some king of e-commerce where user can buy some training-related content like training programs or documentaries. We use Firebase as the database and storage backend, so that when the content is uploaded, a URL is generated and that URL is used to display the content later.

The screenshots the app reviewer attach are the following ones, which clearly shows how the app is capable of fetching content from Firebase database (as the grid/list is showed) but incapable of fetching the images
[image]
[image]

However, I have tested the app on multiple devices, including an iPad that I purchased specifically for testing, and have not been able to replicate the problem. Furthermore, our app's backend is Firebase, and we store all images and videos there. We have a large user base on Android, iOS, and web, and nobody has ever complained about this issue.

I have been in communication with the app review team, but their suggestions for testing and resources have not helped me to resolve the issue. I would really appreciate any suggestions or guidance that the Stack Overflow community could offer to help me identify and fix this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you define some account that the review team can use ?

Comment: Connection refused seems to be inside some library as a fallback mechanism for error or have you coded it in? I believe it should be the best source for debugging this.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, I've created an account for the apple review process, but I've tried using that account and it works perfectly on my devices

Comment: @Shubhank I also thought about that, but that's just the error reported by the image component flutter provides, which shows that the http client cant create a TCP connection to firebase server, although it can get information from the database

Comment: Are you using default Image.network() widget for loading images or any third party cached image loader like https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image OR https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image ?

Comment: @Javierd98 Are you using default Image.network() widget for loading images or any third party cached image loader like pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image OR pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image ?

Comment: @user3930098 I'm currently using cached_network_image, why?

Comment: @Javierd98, Okay. I am using https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image, which is also forked version of cached_network_image. My app also getting rejected from apple app store because of same issue. Today I am gonna try default Image.network() and resubmit into apple app store. Did you tried with Image.network() ?

Comment: @user3930098 No, I didn't try with Image.network, but it may be a good idea, let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: I don’t think it’s the cashed_network_image is causing the issue, as I’m having the same issue with Apple reviewers when they are uploading an image. It’s something related to Cloud Storage and related to Apple’s network most probably: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725134

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

We are aware that some apps that use Firebase Storage have been rejected by Apple and we are working with Apple to help resolve the issue.

You can find more information here: [App Store Rejection Due To Being Unable To Get Data From Firebase](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725134)

**Update: This issue should now be mitigated**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image or https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image then replace it with default Image.network widget. My app was also getting rejected since many days, I was using optimized_cached_image, after using Image.network widget my app got approved.