# Flutter Firebase working on simulator but apple review: an unknown error occurred please check the server response

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, app-store-connect

I am losing my mind here... I tested my Flutter app that uses Firebase and everything is working perfectly fine. On every simulator, on a real device, in TestFlight. Everything is working.

**BUT** the apple reviewer keeps getting an error when trying to upload something to Firebase but the `error` only says:

> `an unknown error occurred please check the server response`

This is where the `error` occurs:

```
 Future<Memory?> addMemory({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String title,
    required List<String> imageFilePaths,
    required DateTime dateTime,
    required String? story,
    int? sortIndexIfEditing,
  }) async {
    try {
      Year currentYear =
          Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false).getCurrentYear();

      Month currentMonth =
          Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false).getCurrentMonth();

      int currentMonthIndex = currentMonth.month;

      String uid = AuthService.currentUser!.uid;

      List<String> imageLocations = [];

      for (String path in imageFilePaths) {
        String uidForLocation = Uuid().v1();

        String imageLocation =
            '$uid/${currentYear.id}/${currentMonth.id}/$uidForLocation';

        await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageLocation).putFile(
              File(path),
            );
        imageLocations.add(imageLocation);
      }
      Memory? memoryToReturn = await _addMemoryToDatabse(
        context: context,
        imageLocations: imageLocations,
        currentYear: currentYear,
        currentMonthIndex: currentMonthIndex,
        title: title,
        dateTime: dateTime,
        story: story,
        sortIndexIfEditing: sortIndexIfEditing,
      );

      return memoryToReturn;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print('addMemory failed: ' + e.message.toString());
      AlertService.showSnackBar(
        title: 'Ups, hier ist etwas schiefgelaufen...',
        description: e.message.toString(),
        isSuccess: false,
      );
      return null;
    }
  }
```

It is not about `Security Rules`, already checked that:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore { 
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }  
    } 
 }
```

What else can this `error` mean? I wish I could provide you with more information, but that's all I got.

Let me know your email if you want access to TestFlight, so you can test it yourself.

Comment: try adding rules to storage like this,

rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Monasha that would open up my `Storage` to everyone and you should definitely not do that.

Comment: Actually, I meant it like changing the "storage" permissions according to your specifications. That was just an example. Have multiple match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }  conditions if you have multiple conditional paths.

Comment: This error is connected with the storage rules you have set on Firebase. However you should be able to replicate this since as far as I know you provide an account to the Apple Reviewer, so you can jump on it and debug it. Also since you are using Firebase enable crash reports and you will have better visibility of what is going on. To be honest I encourage this on all requests in order to be able to understand what is going on with your application when something goes wrong.

Comment: The have tested it with the account I gave them. And everything is working as expected. Nothing is logged. That was the weird thing. But I resubmitted it today (changed nothing in my app) and it got accepted. S

Comment: If this happens only to the Apple Reviewer and only on accessing files in Cloud Storage through Firebase, it is likely the issue raised here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573747/app-store-review-team-reports-connection-refused-error-preventing-image-loadin

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sounds exactly like my case! I will mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Frank suggested, this is a known issue with Firebase Storage.

This is another SO-Question about the same case:

[App Store review team reports 'Connection refused' error preventing image loading when using Firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573747/app-store-review-team-reports-connection-refused-error-preventing-image-loadin)

Btw, my app just got accepted. I changed my `Security Rules` to `allow read, write: if true` which you **SHOULD NOT** do. After it got accepted I changed it back to a secure rule.

I don't know if there was an actual `auth` issue, because my `Firebase-Log` didn't show any rejections.